# How to change webpage code opened directory TCP server python

Tags: python, html, tcp, tcpserver

I've made a file sharing program in Python, which creates an TCP server on the computer it's running on, and shares files from a given directory. To access the files, you go to a link that is created from the computer's IP address. Is there a way for me to change this URL and edit the webpage code?

Currently, the webpage looks like this:
[image: I]

How can I edit the HTML code for this and change the URL so that it's not the computer's IP address?

**EDIT: Added Code**

Here is the code:

```html
import http.server
import socket
import socketserver
import webbrowser
import pyqrcode
from pyqrcode import QRCode
import png
import os

# Create "Outgoing Files" dir #
print(input("Place all items that you want to send into the \"Outgoing Files\" folder in your documents.\nThen press enter.\n"))
user = os.getlogin()
try:
    os.makedirs(f"C:\\Users\\{user}\Documents\Outgoing Files")
except FileExistsError:
    None

# Defines port #
PORT = 8010
# Gets user name #
os.environ["USERPROFILE"]

# Changing dir to access files #
filepath = "Documents\Outgoing Files"
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"]), filepath)
os.chdir(desktop)

# HTTP request #
handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
hostname = socket.gethostname()

# Getting PC IP address #
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
IP = "http://" + sock.getsockname()[0] + ":" + str(PORT)
link = IP

# Turning IP address into QR code #
url = pyqrcode.create(link)

# Opens QR code in browser #
choice = input("Would you like to use the QR code? ")
choice = choice.lower()

picpath = f"C:\\Users\\{user}\Pictures"

if choice == "yes" or choice == "y":
    url.svg(f"{picpath}\ip.svg", scale=8)
    webbrowser.open(f"{picpath}\ip.svg")
else:
    print("QR code not used.")

# Creating HTTP request #
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT,), handler) as httpd:
    if choice == "yes" or choice == "y":
        print("Scan the QR code that opened in your browser.")
        print("Remember to delete your files after you're done!")
    else:
        print("Type this in your browser:", IP)
        print("Remember to delete your files after you're done!")

    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: ". . . so that it's not the computer's IP address?": You'd need either buy a domain to use, or find hosting on an existing service with its own domain like PythonAnywhere or Heroku.

Comment: Is there a way to use a computer set up as a server?

Comment: Setting up a server doesn't really have much to do with it. Your computer is already acting as a server when you run this code (just not a well-optimized one like if you were using a server-oriented OS). If you're expecting other strangers to connect to your site though, it's dangerous to host your own server unless you're a security expert. Website front-ends often act as a vector that lets someone into your computer.

Comment: Is it not secure to use my IP as the URL then?

Comment: Using a plain IP or a domain isn't the concern. If you let someone access your computer (which is happening to a small extent every time someone visits your site), you're allowing malicious actors to poke around your site, find vulnerabilities, then potentially exploit them to compromise your computer. My point was, hosting a website is dangerous. You're better off letting a third-party handle the hosting. If you use a service like Heroku, you even get a subdomain for free (`yourappname.heroku.com`).

Comment: If I were to do this program over LAN instead, would it be more secure? I don't need to access this from anywhere.

Comment: Yes, that would be infinitely more secure; assuming no one has access to your LAN by some means. If you want it to only work locally, you could just go into the `hosts` file on your OS, or the DNS cache in your router/computer, and configure a domain in there to map to the IP of the computer you have the server on. The domain would only be valid locally, but if that's all you need, it would work.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot!